# Java Swing 13 GridLayout does not exist?

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to get a swing GridLayout to work in java 13. The error is that GridLayout cannot be resolved to a type in the following code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    public static final void NewFrame() {
        new GameFrame();
    }
    public GameFrame() {
        this.setSize(1600, 800);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("The Game");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
        MainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit of a newbie, so please don't be excessively hard on me.

Comment: It's not in swing, it is in awt. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridLayout.html you might also need to include the module path, but first fix your import.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it.

Comment: Just wondering: Is there a reason for your method `NewFrame`?

Comment: @MoritzSchmidt This is part of a game that I decided to write in swing.

Comment: Any decent Java IDE, like [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) or [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) would automatically add the appropriate import statement to your code. Are you using one of those IDEs?

Comment: @Abra I am using VScode, and that is where the issue started, because everything else auto-imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the class not being imported.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
```

Since it is not in the swing package it doesn't get imported with the star import.
Also it is better to use explicit imports.

Comment: This basically means that you were using two different JRE, that's why you did not have errors in compile time.

Comment: @yu.pitomets not at all. They didn't import the correct package and were getting a compilation error.

Comment: If there were import incorrect package there will be a compilation problem.

Comment: @yu.pitomets I don't get your point. They claimed the error is cannot resolve to type, and they've included enough code to see that it is pretty clearly is a compiler/ ide error telling them they cannot find the symbol/type.

Answer (score -1):

This might be related to the fact that panel is empty. Try running this code and it should work.

```
public class GridLayoutTest {

private static JButton[] arrayBtn;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // the frame that contains the components
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayoutTest from JCG");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // set the size of the frame
    frame.setSize(350, 350);

    // set the rows and cols of the grid, as well the distances between them
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(5, 3, 10, 10);
    // what layout we want to use for our frame
    frame.setLayout(grid);

    // add a text field with a specified text to the frame
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    text.setText("Result");
    text.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(text);

    // add buttons to the frame
    frame.add(new JButton("+"));
    frame.add(new JButton("="));

    arrayBtn = new JButton[10];
    // add JButtons dynamically
    for(int i=0; i < arrayBtn.length; i++) {
        arrayBtn[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
        frame.add(arrayBtn[i]);
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it responded with the same error, even though I copy-pasted the code.